# SQl query to join a table with Attributes in different rows and filter values

Tags: sql, pivot, hana

I am pretty new to SQL and actually a C# programmer. I have been given a table with PartNumbers that have different attribute Names and Values. The objects would have a class like car, truck, jeep etc... & each class would have different attributes like Milage for CAR & tonnage for Trucks. Each Partnumber may have multiple revisions and the attribute values for these revisons can change.

I would like to query the table for latest revision of the class.

Could someone please help. I have tried multiple options by googleing. May be my dumb brain could not get it right.

ORIGINAL DATABASE TABLE:

| Part Number | REV | AttributeName | AttributeValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 256223 | A | Class | CAR |
| 256223 | A | Milage | 15000 |
| 256223 | A | Seats | 5 |
| 256223 | B | Class | CAR |
| 256223 | B | Milage | 30000 |
| 256223 | B | Seats | 5 |
| 256223 | C | Class | CAR |
| 256223 | C | Milage | 45000 |
| 256223 | C | Seats | 5 |
| 256224 | A | Class | JEEP |
| 256224 | A | Color | RED |
| 256224 | A | Seats | 5 |
| 256224 | B | Class | JEEP |
| 256224 | B | Color | BLUE |
| 256224 | B | Seats | 4 |
| 256224 | C | Class | JEEP |
| 256224 | C | Color | GREEN |
| 256224 | C | Seats | 2 |
| 256225 | 1 | Classi | TRUCK |
| 256225 | 1 | Milage | 30000 |
| 256225 | 1 | Tonnage | 7 |
| 256225 | A | Class | TRUCK |
| 256225 | A | Milage | 60000 |
| 256225 | A | Tonnage | 6 |
| 256225 | B | Class | TRUCK |
| 256225 | B | Milage | 70000 |
| 256225 | B | Tonnage | 12 |
| 256226 | A | Class | CAR |
| 256226 | A | Milage | 5000 |
| 256226 | A | Seats | 5 |
| 256226 | B | Class | CAR |
| 256226 | B | Milage | 8000 |
| 256226 | B | Seats | 5 |
| 256226 | C | Class | CAR |
| 256226 | C | Milage | 12000 |
| 256226 | C | Seats | 5 |
| 256227 | A | Class | JEEP |
| 256227 | A | Color | YELLOW |
| 256227 | A | Seats | 5 |
| 256227 | B | Class | JEEP |
| 256227 | B | Color | BROWN |
| 256227 | B | Seats | 41 |
| 256227 | C | Class | JEEP |
| 256227 | C | Color | TEAL |
| 256227 | C | Seats | 2 |
| 256228 | 1 | Class | TRUCK |

NEED TO QUERY FOR CLASS, SAY EG. 'TRUCK' & GET ONLY THE LATEST REVISION OF ALL TRUCKS

| Part Number | REV | Class | Milage | Tonnage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 256225 | B | TRUCK | 70000 | 12 |
| 256228 | B | TRUCK | 20000 | 20 |

SAY I QUERY FOR CLASS 'CAR'

| Part Number | REV | Class | Milage | Seats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 256223 | C | CAR | 45000 | 5 |
| 256226 | C | CAR | 12000 | 5 |

PLEASE NOTE THAT THE ATTRIBUTES DIFFER FROM CLASS TO CLASS

Thanks a lot in advance.

[SQL Query to get latest revision from Table with different attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp6YJ.png)

Here's what I have tried. Using SQL I first queried the attributes of a single class i needed to get. for eg. CAR using :

```
SELECT distinct attr_name FROM data WHERE partnumber =(SELECT partnumber FROM data WHERE attr_val  = 'CAR' GROUP BY partnumber LIMIT 1);
```

then using the list of attributes i Got, I create an SQL string programmatically to query like :

```
SELECT distinct A0.partnumber,A0.rev,A0.attr_val as "Class",A1.attr_val as "Milage",A2.attr_val AS "Seats"
FROM data as A0,data as A1,data as A2
WHERE A0.attr_name = 'Class'
AND A0.attr_val = 'CAR'
AND (A1.attr_name = 'Milage'
and A1.partnumber = A0.partnumber
AND A1.rev =A0.rev)
AND (A2.attr_name = 'Seats'
AND A2.partnumber = A0.partnumber
AND A2.rev = A0.rev);
```

I get the following Result:

| PartNumber | REV | Class | Milage | Seats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 256223 | A | CAR | 15000 | 5 |
| 256223 | B | CAR | 30000 | 5 |
| 256223 | C | CAR | 45000 | 5 |
| 256226 | A | CAR | 5000 | 5 |
| 256226 | B | CAR | 8000 | 5 |
| 256226 | C | CAR | 12000 | 5 |

Comment: How is the ordering of Revisions decided, is there a data column? Please give sample data and expected results, as text not images, and please show what you tried.

Comment: @Charlieface, Does this data make sense. Please let me know if I need to add any other info. Here's what I have tried. Using SQL I first queried the attributes of a single class i needed to get. for eg. CAR using  SELECT distinct attr_name FROM data
WHERE partnumber =(SELECT partnumber FROM data WHERE attr_val  = 'CAR' GROUP BY partnumber LIMIT 1);

Comment: But how do you decide which revision is the correct one, is based on dates? Or some other ordering?

Comment: Revisions are normally alphabetically ordered. say 0 precedes 1 precedes 2 etc. Then Rev A is greater than any numeric, and A precedes B precedes C etc. I am adding some more data that I tried to the question to show what I have tried. Please let me know if I am on the right direction. Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a similar Issue...Here is How I achieved my results.

```
select partnumber,max(rev),Milage, Seats from (
select partnumber,
       rev,
       'CAR' as class,
       max(case when attr_name = 'Milage' then attr_val end) as Milage,
       max(case when attr_name = 'Seats' then attr_val end) as Seats
 FROM data t
 WHERE exists (select 1 from data tt 
               where t.partnumber = tt.partnumber
                 and tt.attr_name = 'Class'
                 and tt.attr_val = 'CAR'
           )
GROUP BY partnumber, rev)
GROUP BY partnumber;
```

Thank You @ORA-01017 for guiding me in the right Direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggregation` along with `EXISTS` clause as follows:

```
select partnumber,
       rev,
       'YOUR_INPUT' as class,
       max(case when attribute_name = 'Milage' then attribute_value end) as Milage,
       max(case when attribute_name = 'Seats' then attribute_value end) as Seats
  FROM your_Table t
 WHERE exists (select 1 from your_Table tt 
               where t.part_number = tt.part_number
                 and tt.attribute_name = 'Class'
                 and tt.attribute_value = 'YOUR_INPUT')
GROUP BY partnumber, rev;
```

Replace `YOUR_INPUT` with actual values like CAR, JEEP, etc

Comment: Thank You. I think this reduces a lot of steps I used to query the data, but still I get all the revisions of the Table. Similar to what I was getting through the Very long(bad) procedure i used.